# How to change android title color with Coordinator layout and custom toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I'm trying to change this toolbar color **Completly White** like *Android Lollipop Settings* **action bar color** but, there is a bug or something like that in our view or perhaps an Android bug!!

**My toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

and style Arrow:

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, the name is **black!** and after add these also, the search icon is **a little bit black**. (You can try it ;) )

**But i need Completely White color with white actions.**

How can achieve this?

I've tried everything you can expect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this :

taken from : https://github.com/sagar-viradiya/android-design-support-lib-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_collapsing_toolbar.xml

Just add this in the `AppBarLayout`: `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

**e.x:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

For `PopUptheme`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/Main_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

But i have no idea about that search action and why that is still a little bit black.

If some one knows, please guide us.